# Handling C-like strings in C++11

Tags: c++, c, strings, c++11

We have two C-strings and for their concatenation we need to know the size of resulting string. And we want to calculate it at compilation stage. How can I improve this solution?

```
char s1[] = "string1";
char s2[] = "string2";
constexpr auto SIZE = 
sizeof(s1) / sizeof(*s1) + sizeof(s2) / sizeof(*s2) + 2; // + for space and \0
char ss[SIZE];
```

Comment: In what way do you want to improve it? What's wrong with `char ss[] = "string1 string2";`?

Comment: I want to change `s1` and `s2` only, so as `ss` is determined automatically.

Comment: Can you please post an example of some code which 'changes' `s1` and `s2`? And is this all happening when you define global variables, or is it happening inside a function/method?

Comment: I mean I change them manually.

Comment: I do not understand why you have to divide by sizeof(*s1) and s2. You are allocating the same type (char) for ss too. That could be wrong if char is not one byte wide, or useless if it is always 1 byte.

Comment: Are you aware that it's normal to use the `strlen` function? For example, if you're doing this calculation inside a function, where arbitrary string values are passed-in via pointer parameters?

Comment: I specify the sizes (number of elements) of `s1` and `s2`. Either char is one byte or not, I get its sizes by the dividing.

Comment: @ChrisW, but `strlen()` works at runtime. I think it is more correctly to calculate such things at compilation.

Comment: Note: `sizeof(s1) / sizeof(*s1)` already includes the `\0` character. Thus `+ 2` is adding unneeded space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a macro, for example [one of these ones](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4415524/49942).

And you shouldn't need to add `2`: because `sizeof` should already include the terminating `'\0'` of each string. However you could add a comment to explain why you don't add anything: you have two strings each with an implicit terminating `'\0'` ... one of them terminates the concatenated string, and the other is room for the intervening "space": that is, if you think that concatenating strings should add a space, e.g. "string1" plus "string2" becomes "string1 string2". Note that normally, concatenation means that the result is "string1string2", in which case you need to subtract 1.

Your question isn't very clear. You should provide some test cases which demonstrate the expected result and actual result.

Comment: yeah, thx, I mixed it up with `strlen()`. Why should I use macros instead of `sizeof`?

Comment: You don't have to; but if you're going to be doing it a lot, `ARRAY_SIZE(s1) + ARRAY_SIZE(s2) - 1` might be easier to read than `sizeof(s1) / sizeof(*s1) + sizeof(s2) / sizeof(*s2) - 1`.

Answer (score 4):

This is one case where using the preprocessor may be worthwhile (despite the lack of namespace awareness).  In the code below, `ss[]` not only gets an appropriate size without any effort on your part, it's actually populated with the concatenated text at compile time.

```
#define S1 "string1"
#define S2 "string2"

// optionally, create real character arrays so you can modify them etc.
char s1[] = S1;
char s2[] = S2;

// now the magic - automatic concatenation of adjacent string literals
char ss[] = S1 S2;
```